# Angles between edges of a geometric graph and graph invariants

Tags: graph-theory, mg.metric-geometry, computational-geometry, spectral-graph-theory, random-graphs

Are there any clever ways in which the angles between edges in a geometric graph are encoded in the graph spectrum, or another object associated with the graph?

I'm interested to see what else is invariant if the angles between all the existing edges are invariant.

The position vectors (in $d$-dimensional Euclidean space) may vary so long as the angles between the respective edges in the graph do not. Consider the domain in which the vertices are embedded to be the unit square with periodic boundary conditions.

See e.g. [Crossing Angles of Geometric Graphs, K. Arikushi and C. D. Toth, J. Graph Algorithms and App., 18(3) 2014](https://www.emis.de/journals/JGAA/accepted/2014/ArikushiToth2014.18.3.pdf).

[image]

Comment: Why do you think the question may have a "clever" answer?

Comment: Something difficult to spot may be invariant when the angles are all invariant, and this may be encoded in some mathematical object. I suppose this is quite a difficult question as the angles between edges are rarely studied, so perhaps there is nothing there.

Comment: Angles between edges are studied in combinatorial group theory (a version of small cancelation), but usually these are angles at vertices. Say, if a vertex has degree 3, we assign for each two consecutive edges incident to the vertex the angle $2\pi/3$ (in the Euclidean case). I am talking about planar graphs, the so-called van Kampen diagrams.